# Best way to add default rows in DynamoDB table when the stack is deployed

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, microservices, serverless-framework, seeding

There is some application default I would like to be added to the DynamoDB table of each of the microservices when the stack is deployed for the first time.

I am using a Serverless framework. What is the best way to do it?

I came across this https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dynamodb-seed but because of the possibility of overwriting data in the table, I'd like to use a safer option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To seed DynamoDB data post-create with the Serverless Framework you need two things:

1. A script invoking the [AWS DynamoDB SDK Client's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/index.html) `PutItem` or `BatchWriteItem` commands with your seed data<sup>*</sup>.  This is what the `serverless-dynamodb-seed` plugin does. You can write a node.js script yourself, no need for a fancy plugin.
2. A way to trigger the script after a stack create

Which triggering option is "best" depends on your use case.  There are several options, here are two:

1. Run your seed scripts manually from the terminal after you deploy the first time
2. Use the [serverless-scriptable-plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-scriptable-plugin), which *"supports running node.js scripts in any build stage"*, to run the script automatically after the stack is created (but not after updates)

```yaml
# https://github.com/weixu365/serverless-scriptable-plugin
plugins:
  - serverless-scriptable-plugin

custom:
  scriptable:
    hooks:
      after:aws:deploy:deploy:createStack:  path/to/seed-script.js
```

---

* [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/putitemcommand.html) writes a single record, optionally with a condition to prevent overwriting.  [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/batchwriteitemcommand.html) puts several items at once, but without a conditional check.
The `serverless-dynamodb-seed` plugin warns about possible overwrites because it calls `BatchWriteItem` under the hood.